# Make CSS/HTML image shake code trigger without hover/mouseover

Tags: html, css, image

Here's my problem, I have my code here, and it works. Only thing is, I can't seem to make it work when I take away `.shake:hover,`.

I want the image to shake continuously, regardless if it's being hover over or not. In short, I want it to run by itself.

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q245wpg3/)

CSS

```
body {
    background-color:transparent;
}

img {
    display: block;
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spaceboots {
    0% { -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
    10% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
    20% { -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg); }
    30% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
    40% { -webkit-transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
    50% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg); }
    60% { -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
    70% { -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(-1deg); }
    80% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
    90% { -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
}

.shake:hover,
.shake:focus {
    -webkit-animation-name: spaceboots;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.8s;
    -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <center>
        <section class="content">
            <h1></h1>
            <br>
            <br>
            <img src="http://image.flaticon.com/teams/new/1-freepik.jpg" class="shake">
            <h2 class="shake"></h2>
        </section>
    </center>
</body>
```

Comment: Simply replace .shake:hover with .shake, and it will shake all the time.

Comment: That's the problem, it doesn't work when I do that... @DamianBartosik

Comment: It works for me, look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fthLwct0/2/

Comment: Oh I see, you had to removed the "focus" line, if you post in answer I'll vote it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need simply to remove :hover and .shake:focus, so it would look like that:

```
.shake {
  -webkit-animation-name: spaceboots;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.8s;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fthLwct0/2

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
.shake:hover,
.shake:focus {
```

with

```
.shake {
```

Here is the fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/q245wpg3/1/

Answer (score 0):

Replace the .shake:hover,.shake:focus with following css

```
  .shake {
    -webkit-animation-name: spaceboots;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.8s;
    -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    }
```

Comment: Next time you post an answer please provide some information to your code. Simply posting code will do no good. By the way you will get downvotes this way for sure.

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting to hear which browsers you need to support. Since you are only accessing browsers which support the prefix *-webkit-*.

This code will work in the newest Chrome and Firefox browsers:

```
// Removed 'hover' and 'focus'        
.shake {
        -webkit-animation-name: spaceboots;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 0.8s;
        -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    }
```

However it will not work in IE11.

If you want to support a wide variety of browser you will have no fun with animations.

So your options here are:

1. Look up if you can use your desired CSS at http://caniuse.com/
2. Use a prefixer in your workflow. You need a taskrunner like Gulp/Grunt to use a Autoprefixer: https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer
3. Make use of a CSS-Library like Animate.css. Those guys will do the most work of worrying about browser supports (keep in mind that you need to look into the docs for browser support information): https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Megajin